# How to apply variables and filters in parameters passing to an including template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have similar html fragments which I would like to make as a separated template includes:

```
...
<div class='item'>
  <div class='header'>It's a header 1</div>
  <div class='text'>It's a text for paragraph 1.</div>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  <div class='header'>It's a header 2</div>
  <div class='text'>You have {{points}} point{{points|pluralize}}</div>
</div>
...
```

I make an including template **item.html**:

```
<div class='item'>
  <div class='header'>{{header}}</div>
  <div class='text'>{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

And replace the first fragment by:

```
{% include "item.html" with title="It's a header 1" text="It's a text for paragraph 1." %}
{% include "item.html" with title="It's a header 2" text="You have {{points}} point{{points|pluralize}}" %}
```

How to apply filter 'pluralize' in the case we use 'points' context variable and how to apply the value of the variable 'points'?

Now we have `You have {{points}} point{{points|pluralize}}` on output.

Can I do it **without** custom template tags/filters?

**Update**.

It can be another convenient 'DRY' scheme (probably without including template).

**The resolution**.

Thanks to karthikr's advice. I have created the next tag (resolve). It resolves the content of variables:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import escape

register = template.Library()
@register.tag( name="resolve" )

def do_resolve( parser, token ):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endresolve',))

    parser.delete_first_token()

    return ResolveNode( nodelist )

class ResolveNode( template.Node ):
    def __init__( self, nodelist ):
        self.nodelist = nodelist

    def render( self, context ):
        output = self.nodelist.render( context ) # applye children here     
        output = template.Template( output ).render( context )
        return output
```

So, we can change our **item.html** with the tag:

```
<div class='item'>
  <div class='header'>{{header}}</div>
  <div class='text'>{% resolve %}{{text}}{% endresolve %}</div>
</div>
```

Now if we pass as a string with parameters it handles normally.

Comment: why don't you just pass `points` as variable and do the processing in included template?

Comment: @AamirAdnan I would like an including template that does not know anything about what variables are passing.

Comment: since points is coming from the view, can you not just populate the string in the view, and pass it as a parameter into the templatetag?

Comment: @karthikr It's the idea. The problem is that points is coming from a base view, not from a child view. The base view is for many child views. Points is the same for any page of a site. And the problem is that another page has already the variable **points** and the filter **pluralize**, it works normally on the page because I do not use the such including template there.

Comment: another thing you could do is parse the text in the templatetag for {{}} and resolve the context. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-the-renderer

Comment: @karthikr It's a good idea. You can answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea:

In the template tag, you could parse the text for `{{}}` and resolve the context.

This could give you an idea of rendering [template tag nodes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-the-renderer)